# Spinner images are not showing

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, spinner, android-spinner

Folks.

I'm trying to implement dynamic images with custom spinner in android. All went well excpet the images are not show with my condition, It's only appears as the default image in my layout. Can anyone point me what is my mistake? Hereunder my code.

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

int layoutn;
LayoutInflater mInflater;

private final Cursor mCursor;
private final int mLayout;
private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private final Context mContext;


 int arr_images[] = { R.drawable.us,
         R.drawable.uk, R.drawable.eur,
         R.drawable.cn, R.drawable.ml, R.drawable.mr};

public CustomSpinnerAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {

    super(context, R.layout.spinnertext, c, from, to);

    this.mContext = context;
    this.mCursor = c;
    this.mLayout = layout;
    this.mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

private final class ViewHolder {

    public TextView Title;
    public ImageView  flag;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



         final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {


            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mLayout, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();



            viewHolder.Title = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.currencytitle);

            viewHolder.flag = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        }

        else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }




        viewHolder.flag.setImageResource(arr_images[position]);

    return convertView;
}
```

}

EDIT : My listener code and cursor :

```
    mDb = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

String[] headers2 = new String[] {MyDbHelper.COL_Currfirst ,MyDbHelper.COL_Titleone};

```
        cursl = mDb.query(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, headers2, MyDbHelper.COL_Currsecond + "=" + "?",
            new String[] { "EUR" }, null, null, null );






    adapters1 = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.spinnertext, cursl,
            headers2, new int[] { R.id.currencytitle , R.id.titlesub});



    fromc.setAdapter(adapters1);
    toc.setAdapter(adapters1);
```

Comment: When i select any item in my spinner list the flag is appears correctly in the small thumbnails of the spinner but not in the open spinner list !!! any clues?

Comment: can you post the code where you listen for the spinner

Comment: sure, I've added it to my main code

Comment: in your else the viewholder isnt a tag, maybe your dont have it instantiated correctly

Comment: how do i know if i instantiated it incorrectly ?? I've posted the full code above?

Comment: do you want me to put on my version of a spinner with image and text, i cant really figure yours out

Comment: thats all i can do for you, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

row.xml in your layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:padding="3dip"
>
    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
     <TextView
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
         android:padding="3dip"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:id="@+id/company"
         android:text="CoderzHeaven"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

then make your spinners in an .xml layout and in your activity use this to populate them\

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,   String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }


int arr_images[] = { R.drawable.us,
     R.drawable.uk, R.drawable.eur,
     R.drawable.cn, R.drawable.ml, R.drawable.mr};
public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
    View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.company);
    label.setText(strings[position]);

    ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image);
    icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]);

    return row;
    }
}
```

in OnCreate() use it like this

```
Spinner spin;
spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.iconspin);//or whatever the id of your spinner is
String[] strings = new String[] {MyDbHelper.COL_Currfirst ,MyDbHelper.COL_Titleone};
spin.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row, strings));
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and make your activity

```
implement OnItemSelectedListener
```

then you can override this method

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) 
{


    }
```

to deal with the selection of the spinner

Comment: Thanks..I'll try that and will let you know.

Comment: Thanks for your help...I've tried to troubleshoot until i got a working scenario... I will post it for all to help !